# Cross platform multithreading in C++?

Tags: c++, multithreading, cross-platform

Basically, the title explains it all; I'm looking to make a game in C++ and I want to use multithreading for stuff like the physics engine and keeping the animation smooth on the loading screen. I've seen a few multithreading libraries, but I'm wondering which is best for my application, which will work well on Windows Mac and Linux. Does such a library exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can use [c++0x threads](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/C++0xFAQ.html#std-thread), then use that.

If not, boost::thread is the best free multi-platform library.

Comment: Thanks. Is C++0x cross platform though? Sorry for the noob question, but I can't find an answer on the net.

Comment: @JamWaffles Yes, but that really depends whether a compiler supports it. c++0x is still not standardized.

Comment: Ah ok. I've been reading around and it looks good, if a little confusing. I think boost is the way to go, but +1 for the good alternative - I hope this makes it into the C++ standard.

Comment: @JamWaffles C++0x is the new standard. It will likely be finalized this year.

Comment: The committee voted C++0x to FDIS Mar. 25 (couple weeks ago).  The technical work is done, and C++11 just needs the ISO stamp of approval now.

Comment: A more recent cross-platform solution could be https://www.khronos.org/sycl/

Answer (score 6):

You probably want `boost::thread` or Intels' Thread Building Blocks. I'd recommend TBB but it's not free, I think, so `boost::thread` for the free option.

Comment: Free is a requirement pretty damn high on the list :-P Thanks for the Boost recommendation. I've seen it before in various places, but never new it was good for multithreading - thanks!

Comment: Intel's TBB is free, in fact: available under GPL. See http://threadingbuildingblocks.org.

Answer (score 2):

My favourite is [QThread](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qthread.html). Part of [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com) library.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. I'm not too keen on using an entire framework just for multithreading (although Boost is similar), but this will come in handy when I start writing apps in Qt.

Comment: Nope, boost is not similar. Boost is not a framework, but a loose collection of libraries and utilities. If you only need multithreading, you could even extract the boost/thread library only and include/link that one.

Answer (score 1):

Currently my recommendation would be OpenMP (libgomp on g++, IBM XlC++, MSVC++ all support it)

OpenMP offers a simple way of exploiting parallelism without interfering with algorithm design; an OpenMP program compiles and operates correctly in both parallel and serial execution environments. Using OpenMP's directive-based parallelism also simplifies the act of converting existing serial code to efficient parallel code.

See [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163717.aspx)
And [GOMP](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/gomp/)

for starting points

Random quote:

> To remain relevant, free software development tools must support emerging technologies. By implementing OpenMP, GOMP provides a simplified syntax tools for creating software targeted at parallel architectures. OpenMP's platform-neutral syntax meshes well with the portability goals of GCC and other GNU projects

Answer (score 1):

Another nice library that includes cross platform threads is [poco](http://pocoproject.org/)